# from member of nested list, how can I call outside data

Tags: c++

```
struct object {
      string sent ;
      ...// other data declaration
      struct nested {
            void read ( void ) ;
      };
};
```

In read function, how Can I fill sent ?In other words, how can I call sent

EDIT :

I know this is a trivial question, but I donot know so much about nested structure, and can you give any web-site recommandation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nested class simply needs a pointer or reference to the enclosing class.  This can be passed in via the nested class's constructor.

```
struct nested 
{
  nested(object& obj) : m_obj(obj) { }

  object& m_obj;
};
```

You can then access `object::sent` through the `m_obj` reference variable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make some changes to your structure:

```
struct object {
      std::string sent ;

      struct nested {
            void read ( object& obj ) { obj.sent = "FOO"; }
      } bar;
};
```

Firstly, given the `read` function is non static, you need an instance of `nested` in `object` (or outside, I was lazy I put it inside), then you need to pass in an instance of `object` to that function.. you can then call

```
object foo;
foo.bar.read(foo); // this will set it
```

EDIT: If you have more than one function in `nested` that accesses `object`, in the ctor of `object`, construct `bar` with itself (`*this`), so that like Charles says in his answer, `nested` has a reference to the "parent instance".